# Page is freezing on Ajax call

Tags: php, ajax

I am fetching data using Ajax. But when it calls the data, page stop responding and also the loading animation is stopping.

Ajax:

```
$('.filter-form-desktop').on('submit', function(e){
    $('.preloader').fadeIn('slow');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  url,
        data: $('.filter-form-desktop').serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            $('.item-list-main .row').html(response);
            $('.preloader').fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Let me know how can I avoid this?

Thanks.

Comment: check you service.. may be your service returning error..

Comment: @ShazvanHanif it is not returning any error. It is just returning the data.

Comment: check your network panel in inspect element how much time your service is taking

Comment: Can you provide a little more information?

How are you getting the data? Through webservice or page method? what is the value of url?

Comment: `url:  url,` <- I'm pretty sure this is where you're getting your error from.....what's the URL file you want to post to? it should look something like `url: "path/to/file.php",` and your `success: function(response){` should look like `success: function(data){` and your `.html(response);` should be `.html(data);`. I'm not sure about those two last corrections but give it a shot and see if it changes anything.....also make your life easier and instead of this `$('.filter-form-desktop').on('submit', function(e){` do this `$('.filter-form-desktop').submit(function(e){`

Comment: @JeanPaul98 nothing improved

Comment: I'm guessing you have the latest JQuery/Ajax CDN placed on your page correct? `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: @JeanPaul98 yes I have the latest one

Comment: Can you post your form code as well?